# Flatten boolean vector in R

Tags: r, vector, boolean, flatten

How could I get a single boolean value that is TRUE if all values in vector are TRUE and FALSE otherwise? For instance:

```
    > grepl("ABC",c("ABC","ABC","123ABC"))
    [1]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
```

my desired result:

```
    [1] TRUE
```

Another example:

```
    > grepl("ABC",c("ABC","ABC","123ABA"))
    [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

my desired result:

```
    [1] FALSE
```

I know that it could be possibly solved with FOR loop, but this would be a time consuming method. Perhaps there is another, ready and simple solution. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Use `all` :

```
all(grepl("ABC",c("ABC","ABC","123ABC")))
#[1] TRUE

all(grepl("ABC",c("ABC","ABC","123ABA")))
#[1] FALSE
```